# sniff this data with WireShark. want to do this same thing with java programming..?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, sniffing

We are having one multi-para patient monitors (display patient's vital information in ICUs) and one very restrictive software named Central Station which displays the same monitor details on LAN to other computers.

We want to get this monitors data programmatically. Their is no proper documentation available as theses devices are manufactured in china.

So for understanding how its working we have tried to sniff network data between computer and this monitors with the help of `WIRESHARK` application. and it looks like this:

[image]

Now want to do the same thing with java programming (getting data from monitors to computers). can any one help in these??

Thanks.

Comment: "can any one help in these??" - what exactly do you expect people to answer? You're asking this as if you're trying to get a team of volunteers together to go build it.

Comment: @Gimby I mean guide for particular solution...

Comment: I suggest you give this a read if you're wondering why you don't get any responses: [Are “how would I get started?” questions too broad?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308745/are-how-would-i-get-started-questions-too-broad)

Comment: @murtaza.webdev you need to basically implement a computer-program that acts like the server the device connects to - so if the device sends a message to the server, and expects some kind of response/acknowledgement, the server program would just wait for this packet and send the appropriate response back to the device.  Basically, if you replay all traffic the device sends out to either the real server *or* your Java implementation, from the device's perspective, *it's talking to the same server it always was*.

Comment: @Breakthrough Yes I am trying the same with Socket networking... Thanks.